# Why does XMLHttpRequest.abort prevent all Ajax calls except the first inside of a loop

Tags: javascript, ajax, multithreading

I'm tinkering with achieving threading in Javascript by sending bogus Ajax requests.  However I'm surprised at the behavior of my code below.

With xhr.abort() commented out, both "quarter" and "half" get interspersed to the console as I expect.  But if xhr.abort() is called, only "quarter" gets sent to the console, and not "half".

Anybody with insight into how XMLHttpRequest's abort method works or situations where it would be appreciated.  I've looked at documentation at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/XMLHttpRequest and it says "abort()....aborts *the* request if it has already been sent."  The key being *the* *singular* request, not all others, as though XMLHttpRequest is a singleton.

```
function parallelize(bogusUrl, parallelFns) {
    for (var i=0, n=parallelFns.length; i<n; i++) {
        var fn = parallelFns[i]
            ,xhr;

        try {xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()}
        catch (e) {xhr = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP')}

        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhr.readyState == 1) {
                fn();
                //xhr.abort();
            }
        };

        xhr.open('GET', bogusUrl);
        xhr.send(null);
    }
}

parallelize('bogusUrl', [
    function(){setInterval(function(){console.log('quarter')}, 250)},
    function(){setInterval(function(){console.log('half')}, 500)}
]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blocks do not create a scope in JavaScript; only functions do. Thus, every iteration of your loop is sharing the same "xhr" variable, and its value is overwritten on each iteration.

To fix the problem, you can create a separate function to do the xhr work:

```
function doXHR(fn) {
    var xhr = null;

    try {xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()}
    catch (e) {xhr = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP')}

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 1) {
            fn();
            //xhr.abort();
        }
    };

    xhr.open('GET', bogusUrl);
    xhr.send(null);
}
```

Then your loop would look like this:

```
for (var i=0, n=parallelFns.length; i<n; i++)
    doXHR( parallelFns[i] );
```

Comment: I've tried your suggestion with minor improvement modification; passing "bogusUrl" along to the new function, and naming that function bogusXHR.  However I'm still getting the same result as before; see http://jsfiddle.net/a9X7p/  Maybe I'm still doing something wrong?

Comment: I don't understand what it is that's going wrong.  Note that when you try and make an XHR call with a bogus URL like that it's going to fail pretty much immediately.  As it is, you're setting up those interval timers, so the XHR calls just run once and then those timer handlers are called over and over again.